# Whats app sending message via href link and fallback for users without app

Tags: android, ios, whatsapp, deep-linking, fallback

I'm working on a social page that allows the user to select a link that will open whatsapp and send a message to the users chosen contact.

I am currently doing this as shown below.

```
<a class="modal__link modal__link--whatsapp js-product-share__link--wa"
               href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo $whatsappBody . " " . $currentUrl;?>" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">
```

This methods supports both IOS and Android. However my problem is that if whatsapp is not installed on ether devices I simply get a generic error message.

Ideally I would like to be able to redirect the user to the appropriate store to download whatsapp.

Could any one give some insight into what the current method for fallbacking back is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  boolean installed = appInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp");

if(installed){
// do your task
}else{
try {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "com.whatsapp"));
    i.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    ...
}
}


 private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            boolean app_installed;
            try {
                pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
                app_installed = true;
            }
            catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                app_installed = false;
            }
            return app_installed;
        }
```

Try this and let me know if it works

Comment: If it works for you kindly accept the answer as correct and if not let me know so that i can find something else on it

Comment: Forgive my ignorance on this but surly this is only relevant for app development and not when referencing an app in the browser?

Comment: If you want to refer on browser then you can add this in activitynotfoundexception or if you surely want to send on browser then directly add this instead of Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "com.whatsapp") 
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp")));